# Xcode, Map and viewcontroller loop, memory leak

Tags: swift, xcode, memory, memory-leaks, mkmapview

i encountered a memory probelm. Within my project, i have 5 view controllers, one of them contain MKMapview, i loop around these view controllers, everytime i pass the mapview controller, memory doubles, how do i dismiss it?  I searched stackflow and used :

```
mapView.delegate = nil
MapView.removeFromSuperview()
```

This can not solve my problem, because the way i designed my project is like all viewcontrollers is forward looping or like a big circle, my question is can i call any method to remove the mapview from any other viewcontroller? Anyone has any ideas,  Please help me, thanks.

Comment: You are using navigation controller for your navigation cycle?

Comment: Thanks for reply m.  No, i am not using navigation controller bar ,i am using my own custom  buttons to go back and forth

Comment: but you are calling navigationController.push or navigationController.pop? the navigation bar is visual but you are using NavigationController to handle your app navigation?